# check VectorObject is Empty or Null in Java Android

Tags: java, android, object, vector, nullpointerexception

I want to check the VectorObject is Empty or Null in Andorid.

```
if(vectorCustRecipetDB != null && vectorCustRecipetDB.size() != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vectorCustRecipetDB.size(); i++) {
        Some Code
     }
  }
```

but i am  getting Null pointer Exception. please help.

Comment: Where is the `stacktrace` ?? or `logcat` ?

Comment: These lines won't cause an NPE. Post the exception and the code that includes the offending line.

Comment: Impossible with the code you provided.

Comment: okay i got it the problem is in this line txtCustRecCardRouteNo.setText(vectorCustRecipetDB.get(i).route_No);  
 i am getting route no as null.

Comment: thnx for the Quick response.

Comment: @i.n.e.f Have you initialized `txtCustRecCardRouteNo`? Is `vectorCustRecipetDB.get(i)` null?

Comment: actually the problem is i was setting text before i do initialization of txtCustRecCardRouteNo. That's why i am getting this error. Thnx @ZouZou problem Solved.